# Stack divs within li vertically - flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, material-ui

My structure is as below:

```
 <ul className={classes.root}>
    <li className={classes.statsItem}>
      <div className={`${classes.span} ${classes.willGive}`}>₹0</div>
      <div className={classes.span}>You will give</div>
    </li>
    <li className={classes.statsItem}>
      <div className={`${classes.span} ${classes.willGet}`}>₹0</div>
      <div className={classes.span}>You will get</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

What I a trying to achieve
[image]

What it is right now

[image]

I tried using flex-direction column however it doesn't suit me

My css code:

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: `${LAYOUT.FLEX}`,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    margin: '20px 16px',
    minHeight: '87px',
    borderRadius: '4px',
    border: `solid 1px ${COLORS.GREY}`,
    backgroundColor: `${COLORS.WHITE}`,
  },
  statsItem: {
    display: `${LAYOUT.FLEX}`,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: '1 1 auto',
    '&:not(:last-child):after': {
      content: 'close-quote',
      border: `0.5px solid ${COLORS.LIGHT_GREY}`,
      minHeight: '40px',
      margin: 'auto',
    },
  },
  span: {
    fontSize: `${PIXEL_SIZE['14px']}rem`,
    color: `${COLORS.TEXT_GREY}`,
  },
  willGive: {
    color: theme.palette.success.main,
    fontSize: `${1.41 * PIXEL_SIZE['14px']}rem`,
  },
  willGet: {
    color: theme.palette.error.main,
    fontSize: `${1.41 * PIXEL_SIZE['14px']}rem`,
  },
}));
```

When adding flex-direction: column to statsItem

[image]

Comment: since you added `flex-direction: column`, then you need to add another `justify-content: center` for vertical alignment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `flex-direction: column` to the `statsItem` elements.

Flexbox, when implemented in accordance with spec guidelines, defaults to `flex-direction: row`.

Alternatively, you can keep the `row` direction, adding `wrap` to the container and `flex-basis: 100%` to the children, forcing each child to exist in their own row.

- [Force flex item to span full row width](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48101046/3597276)

Comment: Ah, beat me to it!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.lis{
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;}

li{
display:inline-block;
margin-right:20px;}
```

```html
 <ul className='container'}>
    <li className='lis'>
      <div> c₹0</div>
      <div>You will give</div>
    </li>
    <li className='lis'>
      <div>₹0</div>
      <div> will get</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```