# FlexBox - How to display one column 100% and two others 50%

Tags: css, flexbox

Looking at the bellow code, I'm trying to have the 3 child columns as follow:

The first column should be 100% wide and above two other columns.
Two other columns should be bellow the first column and each 50% wide.

Like this:
[image]

```css
.flex-container {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-container .column {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dbdfe5;
    flex: 1;
}

.column.first {
    background: blueviolet;
}

.column.third {
    background: #b4bac0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="column first">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column second">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column third">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

But whatever I try it doesn't work that way.

Is it possible or I'm trying an impossible layout?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48101046/3597276

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flexbox version

You can use `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container to make children that overflow go below, and use `flex-basis: 100%` on the first child and `flex-basis: 50%` on the 2 others.

I have also added `box-sizing: border-box` on the children, to avoid border or padding count in the percentage.

```css
.flex-container {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-container .column {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dbdfe5;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.column.first {
    background: blueviolet;
    flex-basis: 100%;
}

.column.second {
    flex-basis: 50%;
}

.column.third {
    background: #b4bac0;
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="column first">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column second">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column third">Column 3</div>
</div>
```

### Grid version

The grid version is even simpler, you only need `display: grid` on the container, and `grid-column: 1 / 3` on the first child.

```css
.flex-container {
    width: 80%;
    min-height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: grid;
}

.flex-container .column {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dbdfe5;
}

.column.first {
    background: blueviolet;
    grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.column.third {
    background: #b4bac0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="column first">Column 1</div>
  <div class="column second">Column 2</div>
  <div class="column third">Column 3</div>
</div>
```