# How to set 3 items in row FLEXBOX

Tags: html, css

I would like to display 3 items per row, but I want to include margin and border.
Here's is a simple example, but I need to set valid flex property

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: // ???
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force flex item to span full row width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48101046/force-flex-item-to-span-full-row-width)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question.

Instead of margin use `gap` property

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  flex: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.item:nth-child(4),
.item:nth-child(5),
.item:nth-child(6) {
  flex: 0 1 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it like this:
Seeing as you have specified a fixed `width`-value, you could just make each item have a `max-width` of `400px - border and margin`. However, for a more dynamic layout, you could just use `max-width: 1200px` on `box`, so its resizable and responsive.

I prefer to use `gap` instead of `margin` in `flex`-layouts. With this, you can set each items `max-width` to 33.33% (for a 3 row layout), minus the 5px `gap` and the 1px `border`. Also, you don't have to use `display: flex` on the items, as they are already children of a `flex`-container (unless you plan to have more content inside them).
This would produce this:

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1200px;
  flex: 1; /* equal items */
  gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 6px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

However, this is also achievable by using `margin` and a fixed `width`. Then you just have to use the items `margin` and `border` in the `max-width` calculation (5px + 5px + 1px + 1px). Keep in mind when using `margin` in the layout, its also going to affect the `margin` between the container and the items - not just the `gap` between the items.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1200px;
  flex: 1; /* equal items */
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(33.33% - 12px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I rather use flex-basis on child.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 1200px;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: 30%
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>

</div>
```